# Management of columns of primary argument tibbles as secondary arguments, in functional programming in tidyverse

Tags: functional-programming, tidyverse, curly-braces, targets-r-package

```
Functions$diversity <- function(db,entity,trait,v){
  db %>%
summarize(crossed = list(crossing(trait, trait)),
          .by = entity) %>%
  unnest(crossed) %>%
  rename(
    i = trait...1,
    j = trait...2
  ) %>%
  left_join(db %>% transmute(
      entity,
      i = trait,
      p_i = v
    )
  ) %>%
    left_join(db %>% transmute(
      entity,
      j = trait,
      p_j = v
    )
  )
}
```

Here I cannot manage how make the function understand that

- the argument `db` is indeed a `tibble`, but the arguments `entity`, `trait` and `v` are columns of `entity`.
- `trait...1` is the transitory name of a variable of the `unnest`

I know that I should use `paste`, `glue` or `targets` but everything that I try does not seem to work.

UPDATE:

```
f <- function(db, entity, trait) {
  
  db %>%
    summarise(i = crossing({{ trait }},{{ trait }}),
              .by = {{ entity }}) 
}

db <- data.frame(
  entity = c("A", "A", "B", "B"),
  beta = c("X", "Y", "X", "Z")
)

f(db,entity,beta)
```

I think that `crossing` does not work even with curly-curly?
Can you confirm this to me?

Comment: You are right. According to [this issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyr/issues/1397), it does not support this well for now.